# Почему работает неправильно?

Tags: php

```
<?php
  if ($_POST['id'] != 0) {
      $id = $_POST['id'];
  } else {
      $id = 1;
  }
  if ($_GET['id'] == 0) {
  } else {
      $id = $_GET['id'];
  }
  $page = "http://www.heroeswm.ru/clan_info.php?id=" . $id;
  if ($id == 0) {
  } else {          
      include "file.php";
  }
?>
```

Почему file.php выводит до того, как переменная id станет не 0.

Comment: Оно работает, да да.

p.s.
Для тупых: "В вопросе надо писать описание того что делает код, а не тупо спрашивать Какого оно не работает".

Answer (score 2):

```
 if ($_POST['id'] != 0){ $id = $_POST['id']; } else { $id = 1; }
```

Похоже что $_POST['id'] равно null, а значит попадает в секцию else. В случае с $_GET ровно наоборот. Рекумендую почитать о том что такое == и что такое ===. И в чём их разница. А ещё лучше - почитать какие-нибудь книжки по PHP. Глядя на такой код - это первый совет который приходит в голову.

Comment: Кажется я понял в чем проблема. 
>   if ($id == 0)
Тут надо бы 1 вместо 0 поставить и все ок.;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($id == 0) {
} else {          
   include "file.php";
}
```

А что это за конструкция? Не проще сразу проверить на невалидность?

```
if ($id != 0) {
   include "file.php";
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Не проще ли написать типа такого:

```
if ($_POST['id'] > 0)  $id = $_POST['id'];
if ($_GET['id'] > 0)  include "file.php";  ?
```